# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable - Beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to save the scraped data in the Postgres database. 
I want to use django models for this.

I tried to use the Psycopg2 package before, but I found out that it is unnecessary so I decided to use just django models. 
the data did not go to the database also when I used the Psycopg2 package.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxx/Desktop/project/django/tnapp/scrap.py", line 61, in <module>
    scraped_author = author(name='author name')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Scraper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from collections import Counter
import psycopg2
# from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import psycopg2


url = 'https://teonite.com/blog/page/{}/index.html'
all_links = []


headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://teonite.com/blog/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
    all_links.append(article_links)
    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.page-number').text.split('/')[1])


    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        r = s.get(url.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
        all_links.append(article_links)



    all_links = [item for i in all_links for item in i]

    d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    contents = []
    authors = []

    for article in all_links:
        d.get(article)
        soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
        [t.extract() for t in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
        visible_text = soup.getText()
        content = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'post-content'})
        contents.append(content)
        author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
        authors.append(author)
        unique_authors = list(set(authors))
        unique_contents = list(set(contents))

        try:
            print(soup.select_one('.post-title').text)
        except:
            print(article)
            print(soup.select_one('h1').text)
            break  # for debugging
    d.quit()

    scraped_author = author(name='author name')
    author.save()
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, editable=False)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-author_id']
        db_table = 'author'


class stats(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stats = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-stats']
        db_table = 'stats'



class authorStats(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stats = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['stats']
        db_table = 'author_stats'
```

Comment: The error means that, in a particular `artilce`, the `author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})` line failed to find an author. Try posting that `article` link so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Article link?  I've published the whole scraper code above models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things called `author`; your model, and the value you find in the scraped content.

If you followed Python style conventions, this would not happen. You should always give classes, including models, names beginning with capitals. Your model should be called `Author`, not `author` (and the others `Stats` and `AuthorStats`).

Comment: Changed it where? Did you remember to change it where you tried to create an instance of the model?

Comment: I changed it in models, views, serializers and urls

Comment: But not in the scraper, where the error is actually happening?